# Get model.avg to return top model when subset size = 1

Tags: r, mumin

I'm a biologist looking at the habitat association of many bird species. As such, I have a list of global models for each species, and have used dredge on each of them. I now want to use model.avg to get the averaged coefficients for the top models (delta < 2).

However, for some species there is only one top model - the next best model has delta > 2. That's fine by me, but it means `model.avg` throws an error. I would like it to simply return the coefficients of that one top model (in the same way that `mean(5)` returns `5`).

I could use an if clause to find such species and treat them separately, but then the output of, say, `get.models`, is very different to the output of `model.avg` and so I have to go on treating them differently right the way through which is a messy faff.

Is there a simple workaround to get `model.avg` (or a model.avg-like output) to work with a single top model?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

```
tmp <- get.models(x, subset = delta < 2)
  if (length(tmp)==1){
    tmp2 <- c(tmp, tmp)
    mod.avg.results <- model.avg(tmp2)
  }  else {mod.avg.results <- model.avg(x, subset = delta < 2)}
```

(this is in an `llply`, so x is each species' `model.selection` object)

Answer (score 0):

Use `coefTable` or `coef` as a common interface for the component and averaged models. For instance:

```
coefTable(if(nrow(x) == 1) 
     get.models(x, 1)[[1]] 
     else model.avg(x))
```

where `x` is your `"model.selection"` table.